# JSON para POJO retornando Null

Tags: java, json, spring, nosql, pojo

Estou fazendo uma requisição da API do site [swapi](https://swapi.co) e sempre que faço a conversão do JSON para POJO, eu recebo o retorno NULL

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String fooResourceUrl = "https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json";
PlanetaEntity response = restTemplate.getForObject(fooResourceUrl, PlanetaEntity.class);
```

Mas quando não há a conversão, já mando direto para String, o retorno não é nulo.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String fooResourceUrl = "https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json";
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(fooResourceUrl, String.class);
```

Acredito que haja algum problema na minha classe PlanetaEntity, mas que ainda não consegui identificar.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

@Document(collection = "starwars")
public class PlanetaEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8511702512631671990L;

@Id
private ObjectId _id;

private String name;

private String climate;

private String terrain;

private List<String> films
// Getters e Setters
```

Lembrando que estou usando MongoDB para base de dados.

Comment: A URL não retorna os dados de um único planeta, e sim um objeto no qual **um dos campos** (`results`) é uma **lista** de planetas. Então não tem como mapear isso para um único `PlanetaEntity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como citado nos comentários, o seu JSON de retorno possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
"count":61,
"next":"https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json&page=2",
"previous":null,
"results":[{..}]
}
```

Note que a classe PlanetaEntity é o que está dentro de *results*. Para serializar corretamente você precisa usar a classe correspondente correta. Por exemplo:

PlanetaEntityPagination

```
public class PlanetaEntityPagination {
    private Integer count;
    private String next;
    private String previous;
    private List<PlanetaEntity> results;

    //getters e setters
}
```

E seu código mapeando para o Jackson deserializar nessa classe.